# How to get role name for user in Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to figure out how to find user role name in identity framework.

I have such configuration that there will be only one role assigned to a user.

So, I tried using

```
public string GetUserRole(string EmailID, string Password)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(EmailID, Password);
    var roleid= user.Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleId;
}
```

But what I get is just RoleId and not RoleName.

Can anyone help me to find the RoleName for the user?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your code,  `user` object represents the `AspNetUsers` table which has a navigation property `Roles` which represents the `AspNetUserInRoles` table and not the `AspNetRoles` table.
So when you try to navigate through

```
user.Roles.FirstOrDefault()
```

it gives you the `AspNetUserInRoles` which stores UserId and RoleId.

Instead you could try `UserManger`'s `GetRoles` method which will return you `List<string>` of roles user is assigned. But as you mentioned it will be only one role hence you can take first value from the result of `GetRoles` method.

Your function should be similar to one given below:

```
public async string GetUserRole(string EmailID, string Password)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(EmailID, Password);
    string rolename = await _userManager.GetRoles(user.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    return rolename;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you has a list of users you has to do this:

```
var usuarioManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager<Usuario>>();
var roleManager = Request.GetOwinContext().Get<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

var roles = roleManager.Roles.ToList();

var usuarios = usuarioManager.Users.Include(x => x.Roles).ToList();

usuarios.ForEach((x) =>
{
    if (x.Roles.Any())
    {
        var roleDb = roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == x.Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleId);
        if (roleDb != null)
            x.RoleName = roleDb.Name;
        }
});
```