# Ajax pop up box depending on validated user

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction.

I have a log in screen, i have two sets of users.. Suppliers and Admins.. I wanted to make a pop up screen pop up if a supplier logs in... (This will be so they can sign a declaration with a radio button)so before diverting into the backend, then they must accept the declaration. I do not want the pop up to show if they are an admin user.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are doing this with Razor?
I'm also assuming you are using Identity to handle your authentication.

If that's the case you should see this answer first:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45675054/6709649

Get your user's roles with this code:

```
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
    //Return true if any of the found roles are equal to "Supplier"
    bool isSupplier = await _userManager.GetRoles(user.Id).Any(x => x == "Supplier");
```

From there you can create a flag on the model you are passing into the razor view:

```
public class MyViewModel{

  public IsSupplier { get; set; }
  ...

}
```

And then set `MyViewModel.IsSupplier = isSupplier` that you found above. In your razor view you can then use a simple if statement to detect whether you show an ajax popup or not:

```
@if(Model.IsSupplier){
  <!-- Some HTML here to show the popup -->
}
```